# Speed up python requests download speed (by behaving appropriately around throttling)

Tags: python, python-requests, download, throttling

How can I download a file fast using python?

I tried different modules like wget and they all take about the same time to execute.
In this example I will get a file from reddit

https://v.redd.it/rfxd2e2zhet81/DASH_1080.mp4?source=fallback

```
    video_url="https://v.redd.it/rfxd2e2zhet81/DASH_1080.mp4?source=fallback"
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(start)
    response = requests.get(video_url)
    stop = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(stop)
    print("status: " + str(response.status_code))
```

output:

```
2022-04-14 15:59:52.258759
2022-04-14 16:02:03.791324
status: 200
```

Using Firefox the same request completes in seemingly less than a second.

[image: browser download]

A right click and "save video as" is not distinguishable from instant.

My understanding from researching similar questions on stack overflow is that the following minimal example should result in OK download times and only depend on my internet connection. https://www.speedtest.net/ configured for a single connection gives me the following result:

[image: connection speed]

The file is about 20 MB in size and really should not take long to download.

As a control, this call finishes fast.

```
    video_url="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71872663/speed-up-python-requests-download-speed"
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(start)
    response = requests.get(video_url)
    stop = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(stop)
    print("status: " + str(response.status_code))
```

output:

```
2022-04-14 15:58:47.022299
2022-04-14 15:58:47.418743
status: 200
```

I ran the same request against a 40 MB file hosted on my own blob storage:

```
2022-04-14 16:07:59.304382
2022-04-14 16:08:00.729495
status: 200
```

Based on the speed differences using firefox, python and python on other targets it looks like Python is beeing throttled.

How can I use a python script and behave accordingly as to avoid being throttled?

I tried using the headers that firefox was using in its first request to no avail - the outcome was the same.

Comment: You did need 966633 ms (as description imply) XOR 966633 µs (as code imply)?

Comment: fair point - I think my clock is broken - it takes way too long to download.

Comment: @Daweo - I updated the desciption and reran some code. something is off thoug - the code does not complete in less than a second

Comment: @Daweo - ok - clearly I messed up with the delta time. The timestamps are better. You can see that the call took 2 minutes to complete where it actually should have completed in one second.

Comment: `2022-04-14 15:58:47.022299` and `2022-04-14 15:58:47.418743` have exactly same hour:minute that is 15:58 so it did not take 2 minutes

Comment: @Daweo yes - the control running against stackoverflow finishes staggeringly fast. Further up you can see the call which I actually want to speed up.

Comment: If you are not strictly limited to `python` you might give a try [aria2](https://aria2.github.io/) but it might need tinkering with settings to get effect you are desiring

Comment: @Daweo I just tested aria2 - absolutely the correct choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the solution is to get around the python eco system.
I tested the solution that user @Daweo suggested in the comments.

It requires an aria2 installation.

```
video_url="https://v.redd.it/rfxd2e2zhet81/DASH_1080.mp4?source=fallback"
start = datetime.datetime.now()
print(start)
system("aria2c " + video_url)
stop = datetime.datetime.now()
print(stop)
```

the output is:

```
2022-04-15 21:38:09.693262

04/15 21:38:09 [NOTICE] Downloading 1 item(s)

04/15 21:38:10 [NOTICE] Download complete: /.../DASH_1080.mp4

Download Results:
gid   |stat|avg speed  |path/URI
======+====+===========+=======================================================
c2e8ce|OK  |    59MiB/s|/.../DASH_1080.mp4

Status Legend:
(OK):download completed.
2022-04-15 21:38:10.131280
```

So that took something like 400 ms.

Answer (score 0):

> Using Firefox the same request completes in seemingly less than a
> second. A right click and "save video as" is not distinguishable from
> instant.

Observe that you got responses with code 206. [`206 Partial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/206) means that requests were sent, each presumably for different part of file. After download finish parts are welded to recreate file. This might allow shorter download time, if every part is served with similar speed as when there is single download. Such behavior might be emulated using `requests` by sending request with appriopate headers (see linked description of `206 Partial`) and using for example [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), but before that I must warn you that not all servers support partial gimmick and you should carefully calculate if additional burden of creating code for doing so is worth gain you can achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just tried it. I went ahead and got the headers from the successful Firefox call. The python 206 call with the same range as the first firefox 206 call also took 2 minutes to complete. I think I am hitting throttling.